# sed one-liner to convert all uppercase to lowercase?

Tags: regex, sed

I have a textfile in which some words are printed in ALL CAPS. I want to be able to just convert everything in the textfile to lowercase, using `sed`. That means that the first sentence would then read, 'i have a textfile in which some words are printed in all caps.'

Comment: are you aware of the `tr` command? Sometimes it's more suitable than `sed`.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley I wasn't until now. Thanks for pointing it out. But how do I use it to do what I was asking?

Comment: look in the link provided in Raghuram's answer.

Comment: if you must use sed,    cat <input> | sed 'y/ABCDEFÑØÅÆŒ/abcdefñøåæœ/'    <- You must detail all the characters, uppercase to lowercase. I know it's cumbersome to write all those characters, but it will also work with all those international SPECIAL chars. :)

Answer (score 361, accepted):

Here are two methods for doing the conversion using `tr` and `sed`:

#### Using `tr`

**Convert uppercase to lowercase**

```bash
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < input.txt > output.txt
```

**Convert lowercase to uppercase**

```bash
tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' < input.txt > output.txt
```

#### Using `sed` on GNU (but not BSD or Mac)

**Convert uppercase to lowercase**

```bash
sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/' input.txt > output.txt
```

**Convert lowercase to uppercase**

```bash
sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\U\1/' input.txt > output.txt
```

The reason the `sed` version doesn't work on BSD or Mac is because those systems don't support the `\L` or `\U` flags

Comment: I had to choose my own answer because I'm not a fan of answers that just consist of links.

Comment: OSX doesn't support the GNU extensions either :(

Comment: `sed -e 's/.*/\L&/' input.txt > output.txt` for GNU sed works fine too

Comment: @ekkis OSX is using BSD (as mentioned, BSD sed doesn't support it). Try reading the top line of `man sed` to know which version you're using.

Comment: For some reason when I use your upper case pattern, it adds a `U` in front of every line

Comment: In macOS, the workaround is to use GNU sed. Install first using `brew install gnu-sed`. And then to use GNU sed, use `gsed` instead of the macOS bundled `sed`.

Comment: What does \1/ do at the end?

Comment: @r_e `\1` indicates the first "capture group" enclosed in parentheses. The `/` is part of the syntax for a substitution: `s/<search_expression>/<replacement>/`. Thus, the text matched by the parenthesized capture group (`.*`) is output by the replacement.

Comment: Use `\E` to stop case conversion started by `\L` or `\U`. E.g. `'...\U\1\E \2...'`

Answer (score 75):

If you have GNU extensions, you can use sed's \L (lower entire match, or until \L [lower] or \E [end - toggle casing off] is reached), like so:

```
sed 's/.*/\L&/' <input >output
```

Note:  '&' means the full match pattern.

As a side note, GNU extensions include \U (upper), \u (upper next character of match), \l (lower next character of match).  For example, if you wanted to camelcase a sentence:

```
$ sed -E 's/\w+/\u&/g' <<< "Now is the time for all good men..." # Camel Case
Now Is The Time For All Good Men...
```

Note:  Since the assumption is we have GNU extensions, we can use [sequences](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#regexp-extensions) such as `\w` (match a word character) and the `-E` ([extended](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#ERE-syntax) regex) option, which relieves you of having to escape the one-or-more quantifier (`+`) and certain other special regex characters.

Comment: Very useful tip. I've found that the round parentheses are not needed in the camel case example. 's/\w+/\u&/g' also works.

Comment: `sed -ri 's/MATCH_WHATEVER/\L&/i' input-file.ext` - using the `/i` modifier makes the match case-insensitive and thus is optional. The `-i` switch tells sed to alter the file in-place. No need to redirect output to another file if you don't have to.

Comment: I really needed this `\E [end - toggle casing off]`. Thank you !

Comment: Note that the syntax generally seems to be `\L\1`, so `\L&` is an exception with the missing backslash. I tested this and if you add the backslash before the `&` you just get a literal `&`.

Answer (score 50):

You also can do this very easily with `awk`, if you're willing to consider a different tool:

```
echo "UPPER" | awk '{print tolower($0)}'
```

Comment: Its best answer, becouse work with cyrillic.  tr: - didnt work with it.

Comment: Watch out for characters with accents. `tolower` wont be able to handle `À` for instance

Comment: You can rename a bunch of files with that command : 
`ls | awk '{print "mv " $0 " " tolower($0)}' | sh`

Answer (score 21):

Here are many solutions :

To upercaser with perl, tr, sed and awk

```
perl -ne 'print uc'
perl -npe '$_=uc'
perl -npe 'tr/[a-z]/[A-Z]/'
perl -npe 'tr/a-z/A-Z/'
tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'
sed y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/
sed 's/\([a-z]\)/\U\1/g'
sed 's/.*/\U&/'
awk '{print toupper($0)}'
```

To lowercase with perl, tr, sed and awk

```
perl -ne 'print lc'
perl -npe '$_=lc'
perl -npe 'tr/[A-Z]/[a-z]/'
perl -npe 'tr/A-Z/a-z/'
tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'
sed y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/
sed 's/\([A-Z]\)/\L\1/g'
sed 's/.*/\L&/'
awk '{print tolower($0)}'
```

Complicated bash to lowercase :

```
while read v;do v=${v//A/a};v=${v//B/b};v=${v//C/c};v=${v//D/d};v=${v//E/e};v=${v//F/f};v=${v//G/g};v=${v//H/h};v=${v//I/i};v=${v//J/j};v=${v//K/k};v=${v//L/l};v=${v//M/m};v=${v//N/n};v=${v//O/o};v=${v//P/p};v=${v//Q/q};v=${v//R/r};v=${v//S/s};v=${v//T/t};v=${v//U/u};v=${v//V/v};v=${v//W/w};v=${v//X/x};v=${v//Y/y};v=${v//Z/z};echo "$v";done
```

Complicated bash to uppercase :

```
while read v;do v=${v//a/A};v=${v//b/B};v=${v//c/C};v=${v//d/D};v=${v//e/E};v=${v//f/F};v=${v//g/G};v=${v//h/H};v=${v//i/I};v=${v//j/J};v=${v//k/K};v=${v//l/L};v=${v//m/M};v=${v//n/N};v=${v//o/O};v=${v//p/P};v=${v//q/Q};v=${v//r/R};v=${v//s/S};v=${v//t/T};v=${v//u/U};v=${v//v/V};v=${v//w/W};v=${v//x/X};v=${v//y/Y};v=${v//z/Z};echo "$v";done
```

Simple bash to lowercase :

```
while read v;do echo "${v,,}"; done
```

Simple bash to uppercase :

```
while read v;do echo "${v^^}"; done
```

Note that ${v,} and ${v^} only change the first letter.

You should use it that way :

```
(while read v;do echo "${v,,}"; done) < input_file.txt > output_file.txt
```

Comment: \U and \L in sed examples are gnu  extensions. Something to keep in mind if you want it to be more portable

Answer (score 17):

I like some of the answers here, but there is a sed command that should do the trick on any platform:

```
sed 'y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/'
```

Anyway, it's easy to understand.  And knowing about the y command can come in handy sometimes.

Comment: This doesn't work for arbitrary international characters but does work for ASCII characters in OS/X

Comment: It certainly did the job for me. I have to admit it was the first time I used y command. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

If you have GNU sed (likely on Linux, but not on *BSD or macOS):

```
echo  "Hello  MY name is SUJIT "  | sed 's/./\L&/g'
```

Output:

```
hello  my name is sujit
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using posix sed

Selection for any case for a pattern (converting the searched pattern with this sed than use the converted pattern in you wanted command using regex:

```
echo "${MyOrgPattern} | sed "s/[aA]/[aA]/g;s/[bB]/[bB]/g;s/[cC]/[cC]/g;s/[dD]/[dD]/g;s/[eE]/[eE]/g;s/[fF]/[fF]/g;s/[gG]/[gG]/g;s/[hH]/[hH]/g;s/[iI]/[iI]/g;s/[jJ]/[jJ]/g;s/[kK]/[kK]/g;s/[lL]/[lL]/g;s/[mM]/[mM]/g;s/[nN]/[nN]/g;s/[oO]/[oO]/g;s/[pP]/[pP]/g;s/[qQ]/[qQ]/g;s/[rR]/[rR]/g;s/[sS]/[sS]/g;s/[tT]/[tT]/g;s/[uU]/[uU]/g;s/[vV]/[vV]/g;s/[wW]/[wW]/g;s/[xX]/[xX]/g;s/[yY]/[yY]/g;s/[zZ]/[zZ]/g" | read -c MyNewPattern
 YourInputStreamCommand | egrep "${MyNewPattern}"
```

convert in lower case

```
sed "s/[aA]/a/g;s/[bB]/b/g;s/[cC]/c/g;s/[dD]/d/g;s/[eE]/e/g;s/[fF]/f/g;s/[gG]/g/g;s/[hH]/h/g;s/[iI]/i/g;s/j/[jJ]/g;s/[kK]/k/g;s/[lL]/l/g;s/[mM]/m/g;s/[nN]/n/g;s/[oO]/o/g;s/[pP]/p/g;s/[qQ]/q/g;s/[rR]/r/g;s/[sS]/s/g;s/[tT]/t/g;s/[uU]/u/g;s/[vV]/v/g;s/[wW]/w/g;s/[xX]/x/g;s/[yY]/y/g;s/[zZ]/z/g"
```

same for uppercase replace lower letter between // by upper equivalent in the sed

Have fun

Comment: (I found this one worked best on MacOS) - Nice, my friend - but a tiny topo - you have the Jj case backwards. Should be sed  "s/[aA]/a/g;s/[bB]/b/g;s/[cC]/c/g;s/[dD]/d/g;s/[eE]/e/g;s/[fF]/f/g;s/[gG]/g/g;s/[hH]/h/g;s/[iI]/i/g;s/[jJ]/j/g;s/[kK]/k/g;s/[lL]/l/g;s/[mM]/m/g;s/[nN]/n/g;s/[oO]/o/g;s/[pP]/p/g;s/[qQ]/q/g;s/[rR]/r/g;s/[sS]/s/g;s/[tT]/t/g;s/[uU]/u/g;s/[vV]/v/g;s/[wW]/w/g;s/[xX]/x/g;s/[yY]/y/g;s/[zZ]/z/g"

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to do something so labor intensive.  I'm assuming Mac OS does not have GNU extensions, but if you're dead set on using sed, instead of substitution ('s') you could use transliteration ('y') like so:

 sed 'y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/'

Comment: the goal was to select  any text pattern that look like a lower/upper case from a non GNU sed without changing the content of the data source (a `y//` change the content of source or could miss the pattern search.

Answer (score 3):

short, sweet and you don't even need redirection :-)

```
perl -p -i -e 'tr/A-Z/a-z/' file
```

Comment: Hah, well I tried to use this with a look behind and it somehow replaced most of all letters in my files with other random upper case letter. Gave me a good laugh anyway. I was able to to derive what I wanted from this answer too about perl: http://askubuntu.com/a/527073/250556

Answer (score 0):

Instead of typing this long expression:

```
sed 'y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/' input
```

One could use this:

```
sed 'y/'$(printf "%s" {A..Z} "/" {a..z} )'/' input
```