# Do Any Compilers Generate Hex Intel Recs w/ Lowercase Hex Letters?

Tags: hex, intel

Just curious: working on a Intel hex record file parser w/ an ASCII conversion. My compiler generates its Intel hex records with capitalized letters for hex fields. Do some compilers generate their records w/ lowercase hex values?

```
:10001000C4BC5F563E678745456679D421234556F8
```

vs.

```
:10001000c4bc5f563e678745456679d421234556f8
```

The standard only uses capitalized letters, but since it doesn't seem to specifically prohibit lowercasae, I'm guessing some compilers might.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on Linux or some Unix system, you can always make the transformation yourself using a tool like tr. For example, see [sed one-liner to convert all uppercase to lowercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569825/sed-one-liner-to-convert-all-uppercase-to-lowercase)

If you're on Windows, you can find a working tr in msys (you may even have it already if you're using TortoiseGit, for example).