# Convert first letter to lowercase using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am running a Docker Alpine based image which has bash installed.

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-alpine-linux-musl)
```

In the following command, i am trying to convert first letter of month to lowercase but it's not working:

```
find ../ -type f -name "*.md" \
        -exec bash -c '
            f=${1#./}
            gzip -9 "$f"
            mv "$f".gz "$f"
            aws s3 cp "$f" s3://bucket_name/ --metadata time=$(date +%d-%b-%Y.%H%M | sed '\''s#\([A-Z]\)#\L\1#'\'') ' _ {} \;
```

The date attribute it assigns to the file(s) is:

```
"Metadata": {
    "timestamp": "10-LSep-2018.1054"
}
```

`\L` is not working in this case. The expected date should have been `"10-sep-2018.1054"`

How can i get it working with the bash version present in Docker image?

Comment: you claim \L is not working, but your example actually shows an unescaped L. to convert ONLY the first capital of any word to lowercase try `sed -E "s/\b[^A-Z]*[A-Z]/\L&/"`

Comment: @Sam: Extremely sorry for that typo. It's actually \L.

Comment: hm, it works for me, maybe you have a different version of sed? also, perhaps a simple `tr [:upper:] [:lower:]` would be enough for your purposes?

Comment: I just checked the version and it says "This is not GNU sed version 4.0". [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16350/which-sed-version-is-not-gnu-sed-4-0) seems to be the case. Anyways, your first suggestion is not working and it may be because of the reason i just cited. I get this as output: `"L10-Sep-2018.1142"`. Second suggestions works though.

Comment: if it is of no concern that other capital letters need to be retained, i would go with `tr` for better readability.

Comment: @Sam: Kindly post your suggestion as answer. I will definitely wait for some time for a `sed` answer but if nothing comes up, i will accept yours. Though it is wide in its application but for my use-case, i feel it's safe to use it and readable too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out OP only has access to a minimal version of `sed` that does not recognize the \L replacement command and for his use case de-capitalizing ALL letters in the output is acceptable.

The most straightforward way to achieve this is with the command

```
tr [:upper:] [:lower:]
```

Answer (score 1):

The question could have been simplified by only showing the affected part:

```
date +%d-%b-%Y.%H%M | sed '\''s#\([A-Z]\)#L\1#'\''
```

In first place let me "clean" it:

```
date +%d-%b-%Y.%H%M | sed 's#\([A-Z]\)#L\1#'
```

What I see here is that you are using L as a literal letter, not as the command. You need to escape it (\L) like this:

```
date +%d-%b-%Y.%H%M | sed 's#\([A-Z]\)#\L\1#'
```

You can test it executing:

```
:~# docker container run --rm alpine /bin/sh
/ # date +%d-%b-%Y.%H%M | sed 's#\([A-Z]\)#\L\1#'
10-LSep-2018.1510
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but i did not try simplifying because the original version (whole command) that i posted is what i am using. Tried your suggestion but it throws error: `-c: line 4: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'`

Comment: Yes, because my version is not using the needed escaping ('\''something'\''). It seems that your problem is the sed version included in your alpine, that doesn't have this \L command. Have you tried the docker command I gave you to confirm that the sed you are using is the problem? Because I am using alpine:latest (11cd0b38bc3c    2 months ago    4.41MB) and sed is working fine for me.

Comment: If i run your Docker command, it prints the date in correct format. However, if i run the same `Alpine` container with this command, `docker container run --rm alpine sed --version`, i get `This is not GNU sed version 4.0` as output. This is exactly what i get when i print output of `sed --version` in my script. Going with the `sed` version details of yours and mine, i _assume_ `\L` _might_ be supported in my image as well but needs some tweaking in the way i am using it.

Comment: So i just confirmed that my `sed` version _also_ supports `\L`. I just used my container in place of yours in the command you suggested and it's printing the date properly. So as i said earlier, some tweaking is required in the original command i posted.

Comment: I think it is related to the escaping level. Bash escaping (\L) may be working before sed escaping (which will get only L). Can you try double escaping \\L? Like: sed 's#\([A-Z]\)#\\L\1#'

Comment: I have tried that already but the output was the same i.e., `10-LSep-2018.1054`

Comment: ah, sorry, my bad. The docker command I sent is wrong. The pipe command is not executed inside the container, but outside. Only the date command is executed inside the container, then the output is sent to the host, and the host executed the sed command over it. I have verified that the sed command inside alpine image doesn't have the \L command.

Comment: Ok. That's a nice observation :) Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

This [GNU `sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) should do:

```
$ date +'%d-%b-%Y.%H%M' | sed 's/-./\L&/'
10-sep-2018.1332
```

To escape it properly in `bash -c '...'`:

```
bash -c '... time="$(date +"%d-%b-%Y.%H%M" | sed "s/-./\L&/")" ...'
```

---

If you don't have GNU `sed` available (it is needed for the `\L` extension), just save the date to a variable and use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
$ d=$(date +'%d-%b-%Y.%H%M')
$ echo "${d,,}"
10-sep-2018.1337
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that `GNU sed` supports `\L`. +1 for that. I have seen the second variant but i want to avoid handling the date separately. I might go with the `tr` that @Sam suggested if i don't get a `sed` answer.

Comment: Using your latest suggestion, i get the dir name as `10L-Sep-2018.1540`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/$/:JjFfMmAaSsOoNnDd/;s/\([JFMASOND]\)\(.*\):.*\1\(.\).*/\3\2/' file
```

This replaces an upper-case letter J,F,M,A,S,O,N or D with its lower-case complement.

Comment: I tried but i am getting `find: -exec requires an argument`.

Answer (score 0):

There are [few variants of a possible answer in this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569825/sed-one-liner-to-convert-all-uppercase-to-lowercase), but the one that seems to satisfy your needs, and it's also the easiest to read, is the following one:

```
sed 'y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/'
```

That should work pretty much everywhere, including macOS.