# How to (optimally) pick a single normalized random word from a file with bash / sed / shuf?

Tags: bash, sed

I'm looking to remove any non-alphabetic (English) characters and make the output lower-case from `/usr/share/dict/words`. Here's what I have so far:

```sh
sed "$(shuf -i "1-$(cat /usr/share/dict/words | wc -l)" -n 1)q;d" /usr/share/dict/words | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sed 's/[^-a-z]//g'
```

This works fine but is it possible to do it all in the one `sed` command?

---

**EDIT**: The American word file looks like this:

```
A
A's
AMD
AMD's
AOL
AOL's
AWS
AWS's
Aachen
Aachen's
```

I'm looking to make this **lower-case** and **remove any non-alphabetic characters** (as mentioned in my original question). The solution I have works fine but I'm hoping to reduce the number of commands (maybe just `sed`?). Output of the above would then be:

```
a
as
amd
amds
aol
aols
aws
awss
aachen
aachens
```

Comment: `sed` can do `tr` but it can't easily be made to implement `shuf` or `wc`, so, no, unlikely you can do it all  in the one `sed` command

Comment: `I'm hoping to reduce the number of commands` what for? Do a function - it will one command then. `do it all in the one sed command?` sed is turning complete, but any realistic sed script that would solve this will be hundreds of pages long, mostly because of missing arithmetic in sed.

Comment: I know sed can't do `shuf` so I should have been more specific. I am piping sed output into sed and tr so I know there's some optimization that could be done with that but I'm not sed-savvy enough (yet) to know that. I suppose I'll just figure it out myself and post it when I do

Comment: `tr` should be way faster then `sed`, there's nothing to optimize. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569825/sed-one-liner-to-convert-all-uppercase-to-lowercase - does this answer your question?

Comment: `shuf -n 1 </usr/share/dict/words | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | tr -cd '[:lower:]\n'` or with some versions of sed: `shuf -n 1 </usr/share/dict/words | sed 's/.*/\L&/;s/[^[:lower:]]//'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `sed` and `wc` -- `shuf` can shuffle the lines of a file.
`tr` can remove non-alphas, so again don't need `sed`

```sh
shuf -n1 /usr/share/dict/words | tr -dc '[:alpha:]' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

Comment: This is fantastic and it works on all languages. Well done and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This single awk command should do the job:

```sh
awk '{gsub(/[^[:alpha:]]+/, ""); print tolower($0)}' file

a
as
amd
amds
aol
aols
aws
awss
aachen
aachens
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed and shuf):

```
shuf -n1 /usr/share/dict/words | sed 's/[^[:alpha:]-]//g;s/.*/\L&/'
```

Choose a random line, remove any non-alpha (except hyphen) characters and lowercase the result.

Comment: This is pretty good. Something I tried (and failed) to figure out is how to do all of that `sed` stuff to a specific line from a larger file. I got around the issue by piping it in like you're doing here but I wondered, if I know line 17 is what I want then why can't I write `17q;s/...blahblah.../` ... it just didn't do what I expected

Comment: @NeilC.Obremski it is the other way round but also using the `-n` option and `p` flag on the substitution command e.g. `sed -n '17{s/[^[:alpha:]-]//g;s/.*/\L&/p;q}' file`